# how to refresh .dbml sync to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I'm working with `LinqToSql` classes. Here I just want to refresh the .dbml file if any changes occur on the database. Is there any tool available that automatically updates the .dbml if changes occur on the database side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that. The way I do it is to delete changed tables(s) from DBML and drag them back from Server Explorer.

Comment: well i herd about tool/add on like http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/ this can done..

Comment: The tool is discontinued according to their site.

Comment: The tool is back. And free!

Comment: Yes. I am using it (Jan 2016) and its working flaw lessly. I am able to update my table and views from database using this tool.

Comment: Couldn't find how to launch the tool after installing it in VS Community Edition 2015